# Function with array and delineated string as parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is this block of code doing?

```
find_by_sql [<<-SQL, db_time_now, db_time_now]
      UPDATE pages SET locked_at = ?, updated_at = ?
      WHERE id IN (#{pages_subquery})
      RETURNING *
    SQL
```

I'm specifically confused how that SQL is correctly getting passed as the first parameter (what is it called to use the `<<-SQL` notation again?).

`find_by_sql` documentation: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Querying/find_by_sql

This code is from: https://github.com/Genius/trackback_scraper/blob/master/app/models/page.rb#L55-L59

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax is called a [here document](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Here_documents).

It is equivalent to this:

```
find_by_sql ["
  UPDATE pages SET locked_at = ?, updated_at = ?
  WHERE id IN (#{pages_subquery})
  RETURNING *", db_time_now, db_time_now]
```

Basically, typing `<<-SOMETHING` where a string should go will make whatever is on the next few lines in the file until `SOMETHING` is encountered be in that string, if that makes sense.